# Broken f-string Interpolation on Thonny/Raspberry

Tags: python, syntax, python-3.8, f-string

I am struggling in managing to overcome a problem with curly brackets in Python.

I am building a twitter bot, when launching the script from an online IDE (Python 3.8.2) the variables' value is correctly printed:

```
Streak: 87
```

However, when launching the very same script from thonny in raspberry (Python 3.8.0) the bot tweets the variable name in curly brackets instead of the variable's value:

```
Streak: {StreakValue}
```

The code is:

```
tweet = f'''Latest Streak Update
Updated Streak: {StreakValue}
'''
```

I checked documentation but nothing looks different to my eyes between Python 3.8.0 and 3.8.2 in f-string interpolation.

Comment: "f-string" is the keyword, not "curly-bracket management"

Comment: `print(tweet)` works for me, when `StreakValue = 10`

Comment: The only way this could happen is if the script did `StreakValue = 'StreakValue'`

Comment: @Barmar I tried to print to terminal the `StreakValue` variable and it is a number.

Comment: Then there's no way what you wrote could be happening.

Comment: Does string interpolation work correctly the old-fashioned way using `str.format()`?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi thanks you saved me hours :/